# how to display specific items in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, useselector

I am creating a page to display all the tasks that I get from redux. this is how I get my tasks

```
const tasks = useSelector((state)=>state.tasks);
```

I have also search input so the user can enter a value and get all the tasks that contains this value in their names

```
const [search,setSearch] = useState('');

<input onChange={(e)=> {setSearch(e.target.value)} }></input>
```

I created a function that returns the list of tasks based on the search value

```
const getTasksWithSearch = () => {
var myTasks = [];
tasks.forEach((t) => {
if(t.name.search(search) !== -1){
myTasks.push(t); 
}
})
return myTasks ;
}
```

now the problem is that I don't know how to display it. this is how I work with tasks

```
tasks.map((t,index) => (
<div key={index}>my code</div>
))
```

I want to use the return of this function how can I ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a `useState` hook in which you store your tasks.

```
const [searchTasks,setSearchTasks] = useState('');
```

then get advantage of `useEffect` to update your `searchTasks` each time the value of `search` gets updated.

```
useEffect(()=>{
if(search === '') {
setSearchTasks(tasks)
}else{
setSearchTasks(getTasksWithSearch(tasks));
}
},[search])
```

finlly in your `jsx` you display `searchTasks` instead of `tasks`

```
if(searchTasks === ''){
return <div>Loading..<div/>
}else{
return(
<>
...
searchTasks.map((task)=>(
<div key={index}>...</div>
))
</>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In UI it will look like this :

```
{tasks.map((t,index) => (
<div key={index}>{t.name}</div>
))}
```